# Ele tem lá seus 25 anos, "lá seus" seria um locução adverbial de dúvida?

Tags: classe-gramatical

Estou estudando e o professor está mostrando orações que as palavras que geralmente são pronomes demonstrativos, não são. Ele não disse o que "seu" é na oração, portanto fiquei curioso.

Answer (score 1):

A frase se divide em:

Ela/tem lá/ seus 25 anos.

seu é um pronome possessivo.

O pronome=ela
O verbo = tem

lá=advérbio informal, que não significa uma lugar (lá ou cá) señao reforça a ideia de mais ou menos.

seus 25 anos=objeto direto de ter

lá tem valor expletivo (eu sei lá) ou informal.

> O advérbio “lá” (“vamos lá”) é uma marca do registo oral, o que também
>   se poderia considerar no uso da preposição, mas não são do mesmo nível
>   linguístico. Portanto, é suficiente retirar a preposição (vamos lá ver
>   o seu certificado). Boa sorte para as substituições!

[advérbio lá](https://digituma.uma.pt/bitstream/10400.13/1805/1/LivroHelenaRebelo.pdf)

Tenho só uma refêrencia acadêmica para: "**ter lá seus** [x] anos" mas posso afirma que é uma linguagem popular, informal e falada.

> PRONOMES POSSESSIVOS
>
> b) indicar cálculo aproximado.Por exemplo:
>
> Ele já deve ter seus 40 anos.
>
> [seus usado com idade](https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/morf/morf47.php)